# Time slider bar/Seek Bar is not working

Tags: spring, jwplayer

I am working on Java(spring) and try to implement Jwplayer for online streaming ( every thing is working fine While I am using static file( file:upload/bunny_vod.m3u8,) I am facing problem while data comes from server(file: "../packager/m3u8?sessionId=" + sessionid + "&subscriberId=" + subscriberId,) timeSlider progress bar is not working properly please let me know how can I get rid off this problem?
please see the link for code.Here commented part of file source not working and uncommented part is working
http://pastie.org/7990343

Comment: Do you have a link to where the player is actually embedded?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply I am new in spring and jwplayer so I don't know more please see my whole code here.http://pastie.org/7990779